# async / await boilerplate in protractor

Tags: typescript, protractor

I'm trying to use `async` / `await` with `protractor` in `TypeScript`. I'm following the example at: https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/master/exampleTypescript/asyncAwait

It's working fine in my experiments. However, I have to use `await` on every calls related to browser interactions.

For example:

I have a page object for a login page:

login.ts:

```
import {browser, element, by, By, $, $$, ExpectedConditions} from "protractor";
import { DashboardPage } from "./dashboard";
export class LoginPage {
    usernameInput = element(by.id("username"));
    passwordInput = element(by.id("password"));
    loginButton = element(by.id("login_button"));

    async get() {
        await browser.get(login_url);
        return this;
    }

    async getTitle() {
        let title = await browser.getTitle();
        return title;
    }

    async typeUsername(username: string) {
        await this.usernameInput.sendKeys(username);
    }

    async typePassword(password: string) {
        await this.passwordInput.sendKeys(password);
    }

    async login() {
        await this.loginButton.click();
        return new DashboardPage();
    }
}
```

LoginSpec.ts:

```
import {browser, element, by, By, $, $$, ExpectedConditions} from "protractor";
import { LoginPage } from "../pages/login";
describe("Login Page", function() {

    beforeEach(() => {
        // login page is not an angular page.
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
    });

    it("should go to dashboard page after successfully login", async (): Promise<any> => {
        let loginPage = new LoginPage();
        await loginPage.get();
        await loginPage.typeUsername(username);
        await loginPage.typePassword(password);
        let dashboard = await loginPage.login();
        expect(await dashboard.getTitle()).toEqual(`Dashboard`);
    });
});
```

In the above test spec, I have to use many `await` for all the calls to browser interactions. That introduces a lot of boilerplate for `await`.

The question is, is there any idea or way to reduce the boilerplate? Also, is this the right way to use `async` / `await` with `protractor`?

Comment: Well the second best option is to use promise chains, which introduces a lot more boilerplate. I think this is clean and readable code. Seeing an await will tell you that execution is yielded there so global state can change there.

Comment: If you are willing to use pure karma you have the option to use node-fibers

Comment: This seems fine to me. Imo `await` isn't really boilerplate code anyways. If your `loginPage` methods take time to resolve, you need the `await` keyword there to prevent the main thread from blocking. This way your tests will run faster indeed.

Comment: @TamasHegedus, yeah. Promise chaining may introduce more boilerplate. I would prefer `await` in that case.

Comment: @Randy, agree. I'm just hoping there could be some way to hide the page / browser details from the actual test code. For example, if there could be an annotation that tell the js engine or ts transpiler to add `await` to all `async` functions instead of explicitly use `await`, that would make writing the actual test code more easily (no need to remember using `await`). Also, it avoids errors, in case someone forgot use `await`.

Comment: I agree that await can quickly become annoying boilerplate. Here's an example from my own recent experiment: `await component.load();
await component.button.click();
await expect(component.popup.open).toBe(true);
await expect(component.popup.titel).toBe("Confirm title");
await expect(component.popup.question).toBe("Confirm question");
await expect(component.popup.cancel.text).toBe("Cancel");
await expect(component.popup.confirm.text).toBe("Confirm");` I'd love to see a better alternative than this mess.

Comment: Speaking of boilerplate. `async getTitle() {let title = await browser.getTitle(); return title;}` this is just `getTitle(){return browser.getTitle()}`

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately without all these awaits - your code won't be synchronized properly. There are couple of cases when you could omit pasting await - but most of the cases this is necessary, since awaits makes your promises schedule one by one.

Async/Await is still relying on Promises. So your await code works identically to this:

```
it("should go to dashboard page after successfully login", (): Promise<any> => {
    let loginPage = new LoginPage();
    return loginPage.get().then(() => {
        return loginPage.typeUsername(username);
    }).then(() => {
        return loginPage.typePassword(password);
    }).then(()=> {
        return loginPage.login();
    }).then((dashboard)=> {
        return expect(dashboard.getTitle()).toEqual(`Dashboard`);
    })
});
```

So consider awaits like a nice syntax sugar over promise chaining: 
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#option-1-use-classic-promise-chaining

But there is a way to synchronize without putting awaits\thens\generators\callbacks . It called 'fibers'. Unfortunately protractor does not support this, but WebdriverIO uses it to synchronize code:
https://www.facebook.com/ProtractorAngularJS/posts/1950761568515087

Answer (score 1):

You can easily run these in sequence without using `await`, but I recommend sticking with await for readability.

Here is how your code might look without `await`.

```
import { LoginPage } from "../pages/login";

describe("Login Page", function() {

    // mutable crap

    it("should go to dashboard page after successfully login", () => {
        const loginPage = new LoginPage();

        const asyncs = [
            () => loginPage.get(),
            () => loginPage.typeUsername(username),
            () => loginPage.typePassword(password),
            () => loginPage.login(),
            (dashboard: Dashboard) => dashboard.getTitle()
        ];

        const tilePromise = asyncs.reduce((promised, next) => promised.then(next));

        // note the return. this is required
        return titlePromise.then(dashboardTitle => {
            expect(dashboardTitle).toEqual('Dashboard');
        });
    });
});
```

Again, I think `await` is preferable from a readability point of view, but there is nothing in the language that mandates that you use it.